# Copy-Paste from Mac to Emacs of ubuntu

Tags: shortcut-keys, emacs, vmware-fusion

(* I have post the same question on AskDifferent, so far I have not got any answer yet, I guess here fits this question better *)

I use `version 10.9.2 of OS X` and a virtual machine `6.0.5 VMware Fusion`. `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS` has been installed on the virtual machine. In ubuntu I use `Emacs 24.3.1` as editor.

Once emacs of ubuntu is launched, the `Kill Menu` (see `Edit` -> `Paste from Kill Menu`) is empty. If I want to copy a text from Chrome under Mac to Emacs under ubuntu, I can use `Command+C` (which saves the text into the Kill Menu of Emacs) then `Command+V` or `Ctrl+V`.

I can also copy and paste a text within Emacs by using `Command+C` (which also saves the text into the Kill Menu of Emacs) then `Command+V` or `Ctrl+V`.

However, the problem is, after I copy and paste something within Emacs, I could not copy and paste a test from Mac to Emacs anymore by `Command+C` then `Command+V` or `Ctrl+V`: `Command+C` under a Chrome page of Mac can not save the text into the Kill Menu anymore. Consequently, `Command+V` or `Ctrl+V` within Emacs always pastes the last element in the Kill Menu, which is not what I want.

So I have to close and re-launch Emacs to clean the Kill Menu to enable the copy-paste from Mac to Emacs of ubuntu, which is tedious...

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is as follows: after copying and pasting something within Emacs, just press `Option+Alt+K` in Emacs, then I could again copy and paste a text from Mac to Emacs by `Command+C` then `Command+V` or `Ctrl+V`...